# How to insert the same guid in SSIS import

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I am inserting data from csv flat file to sql table using ssis package. I added a new column to the destination table called GUID. I need to insert the same guid for all rows every time the package runs. The problem is that it generates new guid for every row.

Comment: What's the destination table's definition? most important to include is the GUID's column name and type, including the default definition for the column.

Comment: I added a column name GUID with datatype uniqueidentifier. If iset the default value to newid(), each row will get a different guid. I am trying to have the same guid for all rows when the package runs. When the package runs at different time, it should generate a new guid for all rows. Is it possible?

Comment: I would generate the GUID once in the SSIS package and append to each of the rows. Then you will be inserting the same value each time.

Comment: It's possible, yes. You need an extra step in the package to generate the RunID (execute SQL and get the result into a variable), then, when you're inserting data (however you're doing it), pass the RunID variable into the query as a parameter that is selected as the value for the GUID column.

Answer (score 0):

You need an extra step in the package to generate the RunID (execute SQL and get the result into a variable), then, when you're inserting data (however you're doing it), pass the RunID variable into the query as a parameter that is selected as the value for the GUID column.

Comment: How do I generate it in SSIS?  I tried using derived column but not sure how to generate the same guid for all rows

Comment: Im having the same problem. Im loading a data warehouse where the natural key is a GUID and when a record cant be found I need to default it to the generic (-1) GUID. I cannot for the life of me find a way to do this. The only option I have is to insert it into the temp table where the column is a varchar and then convert before inserting into the table using TSQL.